# Create Treeview based on li list selection and Json data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I have a scenario to create tree view with List of  items in ul li and json data, based on my selection of list item a treeview should be created.In tree view heirarchy the first level will be the selected items from list and its  corresponding next level will be the values from json data.please help me with this.

I have posted a OUTPUT of treeview with a li items selected with my data.

JSON DATA
It will be similar format for all list elements

```
data={
  project_name: 'Sales1',
  info: {
    Value1: 'Value1',
    Value2: 'Value2'
   }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1'>Sales 1</li>")
 

  $(document).on('click', '#projects-menu > li', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      }
    } else {
      $("#projects-menu > li").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
  });

})
```

```css
ul.menu {
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

ul.menu li.selected {
  background-color: #23ac61;
}

ul.menu li.disabled:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
  <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Required Output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build all the sub li you can use:

> [Object.values(data.info)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values): ...get an array of a given object's own
> enumerable property values,...

According to your comment I added a function called **createList**:

- 1th argument: where to append the newly created list
- 2th argument: the object or an array of objects
- 3th argument: the value of clicked element in order to search inside the obj..s

Updated Snippet:

```js
function createList(AppendToEle, obj, searchFor, currEle) {
  var objToUse = null;

  if (obj.constructor == Array) {
      obj.forEach(function(ele) {
          if (ele.project_name.toLowerCase() == searchFor.toLowerCase()) {
              objToUse = ele;
          }
      });
  }
  if (obj.constructor == Object) {
      if (obj.project_name.toLowerCase() == searchFor.toLowerCase()) {
          objToUse = obj;
      }
  }
  if (objToUse != null) {
      if (AppendToEle.find('.divList.' + objToUse.project_name.toLowerCase()).length != 0) {
          if ($(currEle).is('.selected')) {
              AppendToEle.find('.divList.' + objToUse.project_name.toLowerCase()).parent().remove();
          } else {
              console.log('Error: list (' + objToUse.project_name.toLowerCase()+  ' ) already created!');
          }
          return;
      }

      var div = $('<div/>');
      div.append($('<ul/>', {class: 'divList ' + objToUse.project_name.toLowerCase()}).append($('<li/>', {value: objToUse.project_name, text: objToUse.project_name})
              .prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom">&nbsp;</span>')).append($('<ul/>')));
      Object.values(objToUse.info).forEach(function(val) {
          div.find('ul:last').append($('<li/>', {value: val, text: val}));
      });
      div.find('ul:first').on('click', function(e) {
          var isVis = !$(this).find('ul').is(':visible');
          $(this).find('ul').toggle(isVis);
          $(this).find('span.glyphicon ').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
      })
      AppendToEle.append(div);
  }
}

var data = {
  project_name: 'Sales1',
  info: {
      Value1: 'Value1',
      Value2: 'Value2'
  }
};
var data1 = [{
  project_name: 'Sales2',
  info: {
      Value1: 'Value2',
      Value2: 'Value2'
  }
},
  {
      project_name: 'Sales1',
      info: {
          Value1: 'Value1',
          Value2: 'Value1'
      }
  }];


$('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1'>Sales 1</li>")
$('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales2'>Sales 2</li>")


$(document).on('click', '#projects-menu > li', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.ctrlKey) {

      // create the list on the fly......
      createList($('body'), data1, this.getAttribute('value'), this);


      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
          $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
          $(this).addClass("selected");
      }
  } else {
      $("#projects-menu > li").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
ul.menu {
    margin-top: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border: solid 2px white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

ul.menu li.selected {
    background-color: #23ac61;
}

ul.menu li.disabled:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}

ul.divList li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="projects">
    <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @kavya Done. On CTRL+CLICK a list is added or removed according to the selection class